# Monotouch/Monodroid - Caching Images/Files on HD + Checking if they have changed on server side

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin.android

To create a better user experience, I would like to cache Images (or other files like text files) on the HD of the smartphone. Some functions I would implement:

- Options to define size of cache (if cache is too big, delete for example oldest files until it's below 90% or so of the cache limit)
- Delete files which have not been accessed for X days
- Check online if the files has been changed. Currently I was thinking to just retrieve the file size of the file online and compare it with the local file (if you update a file, I think there is only a small change that the file size is exactly the same)

Now, I was wondering:

- Does there already exist a framework which can handle this? I can't find anything with google. I do find some things for iOS like AFNetworking, but I prefer cross platform code (I also don't know if AFNetworking is able to do something like that)
- I also find something like ASIDownloadCache: in this case, they ask the server if the file has been modified since X. I see that I can do something similar in C# with myHttpWebResponse.LastModified. Is this reliable for static files?
- How to map URL's on local File Paths? (see below)

For mapping URLs on local files (in the cache), I was just thinking of defining a "Cache" folder somewhere and add the file in location "Cache/" + "URL" (the URL without the http(s):// part). Then checking if the file is already cached is very simple. I could also use a Dictionary and load it in memory, but then I need to serialize it and I'm not sure if it will increase or decrease the performance when there are a lot of entries.

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

You could use SQLLite rather than serializing your objects, and it would lead to a more reliable set of static methods / functions for tracking the content you have pulled down, what dates it occurred, the path to the file, etc. As well as their preferences for the Cache that they kept on the local device.

sqllitenet on the Component Store would help you with that.

Plus the benefit of using SQLLite, is that those helpers.. assuming they used basic System.IO, would cross both platforms.. Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.IOS.  I suppose serialization would work on both platforms and your idea would work, but I really think the SQLLite implementation would be cleaner.. in regards to memory use, when you did need to perform clean-ups..  That file you use to hold "everything" could potentially get large and you'd have to load it into memory.. whereas with SQLLite, you can query.. find the relevant things you need to modify / delete / or sync, and do so.

I do not believe there is anything to handle what you are looking for in Xamarin yet.  Unless you are working with Drop Box Sync..

Answer (score 0):

Redth has a caching image store - https://github.com/Redth/MonoTouch.UrlImageStore - something similar (it may be the same code) is included as part of MonoTouch.Dialog.